# Group data in parent-child structure using database rows from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, grouping

I want this JSON format in PHP but I unable to do this.

```
 {
    "couresList_PVP": [
        {
            "pvp_ad_chptr_id": "9",
            "pvp_ad_chptr_un_id": "1526249608",
            "pvp_ad_chptr_name": "54654",
      
    "offer_chapter_PVP": [
        {
            "pvp_ad_chptr_offr_id": "4",
            "pvp_ad_chptr_un_id": "1526249608",
            "pvp_ad_chptr_offr_un_id": "Offer-1526249608"
        },
        {
            "pvp_ad_chptr_offr_id": "3",
            "pvp_ad_chptr_un_id": "1526249608",
            "pvp_ad_chptr_offr_un_id": "Offer-1526249608"
        }]
},]
}
```

My PHP code is here. How will I do this grouping? I am getting JSON response, but in a different array structure not a nested structure.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT * from `pvp_admin_chptr_list` order by pvp_ad_chptr_id desc");

if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){

    while($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    
        $url=$this->site_url.'images_console/chapter_banner_console/'.$res['pvp_ad_chptr_banner'];
        
        $video=$this->site_url.'video_console/'.$res['pvp_ad_chptr_video_name'];
        
        $images=array('pvp_ad_chptr_banner'=>$url,'pvp_ad_chptr_video_name'=>$video);
        
        $data['couresList_PVP'][]=array_merge($res,$images);
        
        $ofr_sql = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT * from `pvp_admin_chptr_offers` where pvp_ad_chptr_un_id='$res[pvp_ad_chptr_un_id]' order by pvp_ad_chptr_offr_id desc");
        
        if(mysqli_num_rows($ofr_sql) > 0){
        
            while($ofr_res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ofr_sql)){
            
                $data['offer_chapter_PVP'][]=$ofr_res;
                
            }
        }else{
        
            $data['offer_chapter_PVP'][]=array("status"=>"No Data FOund"); 
            
        }
    }
    //$data2=array_merge($data['couresList_PVP'],$data['offer_chapter_PVP']);
    //$data[]=array_push( $data['couresList_PVP'],$data['offer_chapter_PVP']);
    //$data=
    // If success everything is good send header as "OK" and user details
    
    $this->response($this->json($data), 200);
}
```

Comment: can you paste a `json_encode($data, true);` please?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to avoid iterated trips to the database. Instead, use a JOIN query to fetch everything you need in one trip.

While iterating populate a parent data set for each unique `pvp_ad_chptr_un_id`. Push a new element into the result array as a reference with the baseline data. Then push a child array into that group when the same id is found in another row.

If it is possible for a `list` row to not have any children in the `offers` table, then use `LEFT JOIN` check for non-null values before pushing child data sets into the group.

Untested Code:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT lst.pvp_ad_chptr_id,
           lst.pvp_ad_chptr_un_id,
           lst.pvp_ad_chptr_name,
           lst.pvp_ad_chptr_banner,
           lst.pvp_ad_chptr_video_name,
           ofr.pvp_ad_chptr_offr_id,
           ofr.pvp_ad_chptr_offr_un_id
    FROM pvp_admin_chptr_list lst
    JOIN pvp_admin_chptr_offers ofr ON lst.pvp_ad_chptr_un_id = ofr.pvp_ad_chptr_un_id
    ORDER BY lst.pvp_ad_chptr_id DESC,
             ofr.pvp_ad_chptr_offr_id DESC
SQL;

$data = [];
foreach ($this->db->query($sql) as $row) {
    if (!isset($ref[$row['pvp_ad_chptr_un_id']])) {
        $ref[$row['pvp_ad_chptr_un_id']] = [
            'pvp_ad_chptr_id' => $row['pvp_ad_chptr_id'],
            'pvp_ad_chptr_un_id' => $row['pvp_ad_chptr_un_id'],
            'pvp_ad_chptr_name' => $row['pvp_ad_chptr_name'],
            'pvp_ad_chptr_banner' => $this->site_url . 'images_console/chapter_banner_console/' . $row['pvp_ad_chptr_banner'],
            'pvp_ad_chptr_video_name' => $this->site_url . 'video_console/' . $row['pvp_ad_chptr_video_name'],
            'offer_chapter_PVP' => [],
        ];
        $data['courseList_PVP'][] =& $ref[$row['pvp_ad_chptr_un_id']];
    }
    $ref[$row['pvp_ad_chptr_un_id']]['offer_chapter_PVP'][] = [
        'pvp_ad_chptr_offr_id' => $row['pvp_ad_chptr_offr_id'],
        'pvp_ad_chptr_un_id' => $row['pvp_ad_chptr_un_id'],
        'pvp_ad_chptr_offr_un_id' => $row['pvp_ad_chptr_offr_un_id'],
    ];
}
$this->response($this->json($data), 200);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use combination of array and then encode it in json. please check below code.

```
$response = array();
$responseObj = array();
$courseList = array();
$courseArr = array();
while($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $courseList['pvp_ad_chptr_id'] = $res['id'];
    $courseList['pvp_ad_chptr_un_id'] = $res['pvp_ad_chptr_un_id'];
    $courseList['pvp_ad_chptr_name'] = $res['pvp_ad_chptr_name'];

    $ofr_sql = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT * from `pvp_admin_chptr_offers` where pvp_ad_chptr_un_id='$res[pvp_ad_chptr_un_id]' order by pvp_ad_chptr_offr_id desc");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($ofr_sql) > 0){
        while($ofr_res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ofr_sql)){
            $courseList['offer_chapter_PVP'][]=$ofr_res;
        }
    }else{
        $courseList[$i]['offer_chapter_PVP'][]=array("status"=>"No Data FOund");
    }
    $courseArr[] = $courseList;
}
$response['couresList_PVP'] = $courseArr;
$responseObj = $response;
echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode($responseObj);
echo '</pre>';
```